# Length of Gaussian distributed variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Suppose I have a set of random variables $x_1,...,x_n$ s.t. $x_i\sim N(\bar{x}_i,\sigma_i^2)$. And I define a new variable $x=\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}$, then will $x$ also be normally distributed? And if so, what will its standard deviation be? (The RMS of $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n$ perhaps?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for the fast response!

Comment: @LordSoth: If you write that into an answer, user2584283 could accept it, you will get points, the question will be marked as answered, and everyone will live happily ever after.

Comment: Another road to universal eternal happiness is that @user2584283 writes an answer themselves and, after a while, accepts it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $x$ variable will be $\chi$-distributed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution